# "Prove that ∂A ∪ Int(A) = Cl(A)"

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The question comes from “Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied” by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa.

I have very little knowledge of set theory and proofs, so I'm not sure how to prove this. As always, I appreciate any help.

Some definitions from the textbook:

Let A be a subset of a topological space X. The interior of A, denoted Å or Int(A), is the union of all open sets contained in A. The closure of A, denoted Ā or Cl(A), is the intersection of all closed sets containing A.

∂A = Cl(A) − Int(A)

∂A = Cl(A) ∩ X – Int(A)

∂A = Cl(A) ∩ Cl(X − A)

"Let A be a subset of a topological space X. Prove that ∂A ∪ Int(A) = Cl(A)"

Comment: This follows directly from ["Prove that ∂A is closed given ∂A = Cl(A) − Int(A)"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264551/prove-that-%e2%88%82a-is-closed-given-%e2%88%82a-cla-%e2%88%92-inta)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how it follows and I don't see it. Could definitely use a hint.

Comment: Topology questions should not be tagged elementary set theory!

Comment: $\partial A = \operatorname{Cl}(A) \setminus \operatorname{Int}(A)$, now take the union on both sides with $\operatorname{Int}(A)$ (and using (in your notation) that $(C-D) \cup D=C$, for any $C,D$)  we get the result.